# setState using prevState failed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What's wrong with my react method below

```
toggleReply = () => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({ reply: !prevState.reply }))
    }
```

I know I can do`this.setState({reply: !this.state.reply})`but above code will also work, but it didn't, any clue?

Comment: What didn't work? Is there an error?

Comment: @AndrewLi it has error.

Comment: What *is it*...?

Comment: you should probably also rest/spread out your previous state

Comment: agree, you are missing the `(` `)` in `(prevState) =>`

Comment: I always use `return` in the result, but that should work ok

Comment: you don't need the `( )` if you only care about the `prevState`. If you wanted the `props` too, then you would need to include the `( )` around both params.

Comment: oh ok, then maybe the return is missing? we need to know the error message really...

Comment: @UXDart, not even that , return is required when you write the callback function within `{}`. In OP case its within `()` which automatically returns

Comment: maybe `this` is outside of any scope... it is defined as `toggleReply = () => {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `setState` works, as per the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate) - try this snippet below. This is assuming you Component class is correctly defined and your toggleReply handler is either bound to `this` during construction, or you're using an arrow function to call it.

```js
class Thing extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { reply: false };
        this.toggleReply = this.toggleReply.bind(this);
    }

    toggleReply() {
        this.setState(prevState => ({ reply: !prevState.reply }))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.toggleReply}>Toggle Reply</button>
                <span>{` ${this.state.reply}`}</span>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Thing />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src=" https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure ES7 class properties are enabled:

https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/

That is what allows you to use the arrow function inside of your class with proper this bindings. Otherwise you have to manually bind it using a regular function like the other answer describes.

Comment: You don't need ES7 for this - ES6 arrow functions will do the job also e.g. `<button onClick={() => this.toggleReply()}>Toggle Reply</button>` would also work in my example above and you could remove the bind from the constructor.

Comment: Sure you don't technically need it, but I assumed from the code posted that s/he was using the ES7 class properties feature. And manual binding/arrows in render() is slower, I would just use either class properties with the correct Babel config or bind it in the constructor like you did in your answer.